# Regular Expressions in Objective-C and Core Data

Tags: objective-c, regex, core-data

Is there a guide to using regular expressions in objective c?
Specifically what to type into the "Reg. Ex." field in a core data property?

In particular, how to limit input to a set amount of numbers/letters only, and for UK Post Codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Apple documentation, the NSPredicate regex support implements the ICU package, so check their pages for documentation:

[ICU Regex Documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

For example, a regular expression of [0-9a-zA-Z]{5} could be used match on exactly 5 numbers or letters. (So would the shorter form of [\w\d]{5} though that also permits a few other characters)

Comment: +1 correct, except that `\w` is an alphasymnumeric character class.  In other words, `\w\d` is redundant, and just `\w` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation is great!

Answer (score 3):

[RegexKit *Lite*](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) is a wrapper for the ICU regex library which adds a couple of methods to NSString that makes working with ICU a lot easier.

It also includes a short reference for the ICU regex syntax. For tutorials and a more complete reference I recommend [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which is really handy whenever I write regular expressions.

Comment: +1 whenever i have a regex question, www.regular-expressions.info almost always has the answer.