# Regular expression for numbers

Tags: iphone, regex, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I need a regular expression to detect at least one number in a string. Other characters can be anything. Please help me to implement this in objective C.

Regards,

Dilshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a digit anywhere in string use `.*\\d.*`. To implement in objective-c use `NSPredicate` try something like this:

```
NSString *matchphrase = @".*\\d.*";
  BOOL match = NO;
  NSString *item = @"string with d1g1it";
  NSPredicate *matchPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", matchphrase];
  match = [matchPred evaluateWithObject:item];
```

More [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/04/cocoa-dev-the-joy-of-nspredicates-and-matching-strings.ars)

Edited according Dislhan comment.

Comment: Expected answer. Works perfectly. Thanks Maciulis. Small correction @".*\\d.*" instead of "@".*\d.*"" otherwise it will result in compiler warning -> Unknown escape sequence \d

Answer (score 5):

```
\d+
```

Match one or more digit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very similar question to:

[Regular Expressions in Objective-C and Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737788/regular-expressions-in-objective-c-and-core-data)

Check [ICU Regex Documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) for figuring out your regular expression needs